# Is there a commentary for this verse in the Gautama Dharma Sutras?

Tags: dharma, sin

The Gautama Dharma Sutras on sacred-texts.com apparently says [there](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe02/sbe0286.htm) that it's not a sin to kill a prostitute:

> 15. For (killing) a Vaisya (the same penance must be performed) during three years; and he shall give one hundred cows and one bull.
>
> ...
>
> 18. (The penance for killing) a cow is the same as for (the murder of) a Vaisya.
>
> ...
>
> 27. **(For killing a woman who subsists) by harlotry, nothing at all.**

Is there a commentary for this verse? sacred-texts does not mention any commentary for this verse. Haradatta is one commentator for the Gautama Dharma Sutras. He comments on other verses but not this one according to sacred-texts.

Comment: You answered your own question by giving the answer in the body according to Gautama Dharma Sutras that there is no sin attached when we do that. The question (or at least the title) should be rephrased if you are looking for commentary on the verse/other supporting verses from other texts/explanation  Asking if it's correct may lead to opinions.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Ok, I changed the question and body.